# How does peer resolving in utorrent work in this case?

Tags: resolution, utorrent

In utorrent peers tab, i noticed peer, whose ip address was resolved to localhost.

When i disabled dns resolving, it displayed ordinary ip address (not 127.0.0.1) .

How is it possible to make one's ip address resolve as "localhost" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution of IP addresses to names is done by first converting the address to a special domain name ending with `in-addr.arpa.` or `ip6.arpa.` (for example, 1.2.3.4 would be `4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa.`.), then looking for PTR records on that domain, and using whatever results received as the final name.

These domains, however, work exactly like any other domain – there is no *requirement* that the PTR record points to a name that points back to the address, or to *any* address for that matter. The only validation, if any, is done by end software (μTorrent doesn't bother).

(There are no restrictions on the number or type of records, either – zero or multiple PTRs are legal. It's even possible, for the crazy, to host a website or receive mail on an `arpa.` domain.)

Corporate clients usually have direct access to rDNS of their own IP address blocks, while home users have to ask their ISP – which *may* implement some form of verification.

---

To test reverse DNS on Windows, you can use `nslookup` on the command line – either automatically:

```
nslookup 64.34.119.12
```

or do the conversion yourself:

```
nslookup -q=ptr 12.119.34.64.in-addr.arpa.
```